# Is there a simple algorithm or process for maximizing quantity

Tags: optimization, algorithmic-trading

Is there a simple algorithm or process for maximizing quantity. Assume there are two products, A and B. The price of each changes each day and is independent of the other. You start with 100 units of A. Each day you can exchange (sell and buy) one product for the other. Your objective is to increase your quantity of A over say 100 days/iterations. What process do you use?

| Price of A | Quantity | Price of B | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $10 | 100 | $43 | 0 |
| $11 | - | $39 | - |
| $12 | - | $41 | - |

Note: I’m using prices and products in this example, but the problem could involve any countable thing with a variable feature.

I've modeled this process with excel/numbers using combinations of buy hi/lo, random, etc., with decent results, but I'm sure this is a problem that has already been studied. I just haven't found much on this topic in my research so far.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a simple algorithm or process for maximizing quantity

To make it a little easier you can reduce the problem to a single unknown variable - "price of A / price of B". To maximize your quantity of A; you want to exchange all of your A for B when "price of A / price of B" will decrease on the next day/iteration, and exchange all of your B for A when "price of A / price of B" will increase on the next day/iteration.

However, to do this (to guarantee you maximize the quantity of A) you have to accurately predict the future with no mistakes.

If you can't predict the future with no mistakes, the best you can do is rely on "statistical probability" to try to increase your quantity of A (with a risk that you will fail and reduce your quantity of A, and an extremely low chance that you'll "maximize your quantity of A by accident").

If you can't predict the future at all, then it just becomes pure luck (better to do nothing and keep the quantity of A you already have). For an example; over 100 days/iterations, you could spend the first 50 days gathering information about how prices change (e.g. calculate "past min/max/average prices" and maybe find that "price of A / price of B" was always between 0.2 and 0.3 for the first 50 days/iterations); but it'd be foolish to merely assume that the past predicts the future in any way at all (e.g. the "price of A / price of B" might suddenly jump in any direction and never return to the range of previously seen values).

**In other words; to improve your probability of increasing your quantity of A you need to improve your ability to predict the future; and to improve your ability to predict the future you need more information than what was provided.**